# How can I filter/select data (float, text) from a table and plot it?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

**Note**

I post this question in addition to a recent question (see below) with a more detailed description of the problem:

This was the original question: 
[How can I filter/select data from a table and plot it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/how-can-i-filter-select-data-from-a-table-and-plot-it)

**Description**

Now, this is the specific problem:
I have a table with data and before anything I sort the data by one of the columns. Then I would like to do the following

- filter only the rows that contain a specific **text**
- filter again, but now only the rows that contain a specific value (which may also be a **float** number or an **empty cell**)
- plot the filtered data as a table
- plot one of the columns with the filtered data as x and another one as y in a diagram.

Here is an example of my table and the code to sort it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}
%table with data, empty cells contain 'nan'
\pgfplotstableread{
L   C   T   D   V
A   0   20  1.00346 205
A   0   23  1.00118 177
A   0   25  0.99964 155
A   0   30  0.99579 115
A   0   40  0.98807 69.5
A   9.2 20  0.98444 nan
A   9.2 30  0.97664 66
A   9.2 40  0.96862 43
A   30  20  0.96936 nan
A   30  23  0.96622 16.1
A   30  30  0.964   15.3
B   0   20  1.05104 535
B   0   23  1.04876 439
B   0   25  1.0472  373
B   0   30  1.04327 234
B   0   40  1.03555 115
B   9.6 20  1.02981 nan
B   9.6 23  1.02749 152
B   9.6 25  1.0259  134
}\data

\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={T}]{\sorted}{\data} %get the data and sort by column 'T'

\end{document}
```

Now I want to **filter** the first column *L* to select the desired sample.
Then I want to **filter again** the remaining data by column *C* to get the desired property.
In the [question that I posted recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/how-can-i-filter-select-data-from-a-table-and-plot-it) this turned out to be a problem because I simplified the problem too much as it is important if the column contains text, integer or float values.

The generated code for filtering one column with float values (here: column *C*) while plotting the diagram looked like that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     xlabel=T,
     ylabel=D,
    x filter/.code={\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{C}\of{\sorted}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tempva}{abs(\pgfplotsretval - 9.2) == 0 ? 1: 0}
                    \ifnum\tempva>0%true
                    \else%false
                    \def\pgfmathresult{}
                    \fi
                   },
    ]
   \addplot[only marks] table[x=T,y=C] {\sorted};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

**Note:** In my original question I erased the first column *L* to simplify the problem as it contains `text`.

So now, sorting works fine but filtering seems to be my problem.

**The question is:** How can I set 2 filters and finally plot the remaining data as a table to have a whole overview and then plot a diagram by chosing my desired columns with the data.

Answer (score 12):

I have used the [`xstring`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xstring) package for text comparison which can also be used to compare numbers if the number of digits are fixed.

**EDIT** Added the missing table typesetting part. Filtered B-9.6 entries for the table and A-9.2 entries for the plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,xstring} 

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
L   C   T   D   V
A   0   20  1.00346 205
A   0   23  1.00118 177
A   0   25  0.99964 155
A   0   30  0.99579 115
A   0   40  0.98807 69.5
A   9.2 20  0.98444 nan
A   9.2 30  0.97664 66
A   9.2 40  0.96862 43
A   30  20  0.96936 nan
A   30  23  0.96622 16.1
A   30  30  0.964   15.3
B   0   20  1.05104 535
B   0   23  1.04876 439
B   0   25  1.0472  373
B   0   30  1.04327 234
B   0   40  1.03555 115
B   9.6 20  1.02981 nan
B   9.6 23  1.02749 152
B   9.6 25  1.0259  134
}\data
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={T}]{\sorted}{\data} %get the data and sort by column 'T'

\pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{L}\of{\sorted}
                    \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{B}{%TRUE
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{C}\of{\sorted}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tempva}{abs(\pgfplotsretval - 9.6) == 0 ? 1: 0}
                    \ifnum\tempva>0%true
                    \else%false
                    \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
                    \fi}
                    {%FALSE
                    \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
                    } 
},
columns/L/.style={string type}
] {\sorted}

%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     xlabel=D,
     ylabel=V,
    x filter/.code={\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{L}\of{\sorted}
                     \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{A}{
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{C}\of{\sorted}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tempva}{abs(\pgfplotsretval - 9.2) == 0 ? 1: 0}
                    \ifnum\tempva>0%true
                    \else%false
                    \def\pgfmathresult{}
                    \fi}
                    {
                    \def\pgfmathresult{}
                    }
                   },
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/precision=3}
    ]
   \addplot[only marks] table[x=D,y=V] {\sorted};
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, really thank you. That works fine. I tried to use the same code now to plot the table, but there I got an error: **Runaway argument?**. I used it as following: `\pgfplotstabletypeset[row predicate/.code={%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{L}\of{\sorted}             \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{A}{                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{C}\of{\sorted}    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tempva}{abs(\pgfplotsretval - 9.2) == 0 ? 1: 0}
    \ifnum\tempva>0%true
    \else%false
    \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi}]
    {\sorted}` Isn't that correct?

Comment: @wonder See the edit for the table. There are a few differences between table row predicate and x filter such as: `\coordindex` belongs to `pgfplots` but not to the `pgfplotstable` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I see, that's why I have to use `\pgfplotstableuserowfalse` instead.