# pgfplot: equidistant bars, different colours for groups

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart

I have a document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Thing;Weight
Dog 1;50
Dog 2;45
Cat 1;10
Cat 2;10
Cat 3;11
Parrot;3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\table}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[%
        ybar=3mm,%
        xtick=data,%
        xticklabels from table={\table}{Thing},%
        x tick label style={rotate=60},%
        nodes near coords%
    ]%
        \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=1,col sep=semicolon] {\table};%
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to have the two dog bars in one colour, the three cat bars in a different colour and so on. The bars should be equidistant.

I know, each addplot gets its own colour. I would have to make one plot for each group (animal/thing). But pgfplots uses only the first plot for the xticklabels. I could make one table containing all groups with all y values set to 0 and have nodes near coords only plotted if the y value isn’t 0, and then for each group a seperate table with the actual data. But that is a rather ugly hack, as it plots plots over an effectively invisible plot (with `bar shift = 0`). Is there an elegant way to group bars using colours (not vertical spaces)?

From all I found here on TSX, for my actual document I tinkered this hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{data_b.csv}
Thing;Weight
Dog 1;0
Dog 2;0
Cat 1;0
Cat 2;0
Cat 3;0
Parrot;0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data_b_dog.csv}
Thing;Weight
Dog 1;50
Dog 2;45
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data_b_cat.csv}
Thing;Weight
Cat 1;10
Cat 2;10
Cat 3;11
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data_b_parrot.csv}
Thing;Weight
Parrot;3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data_b.csv}{\tableall}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data_b_dog.csv}{\tabledog}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data_b_cat.csv}{\tablecat}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data_b_parrot.csv}{\tableparrot}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[%
        ybar=3mm,%
        xtick=data,%
        xticklabels from table={\tableall}{Thing},%
        x tick label style={rotate=60},%
        nodes near coords={%
            \pgfkeys{%
                /pgf/fpu=true,%
                /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,%
            }%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Y}{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
            \ifthenelse{\Y=0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}%
        },%
        every axis plot/.append style={bar shift = 0}%
    ]%
        \addplot[draw=none] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=1,col sep=semicolon] {\tableall};%
        \addplot[blue,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=1,col sep=semicolon] {\tabledog};%
        \addplot[green,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex+2,y index=1,col sep=semicolon] {\tablecat};%
        \addplot[red,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex+5,y index=1,col sep=semicolon] {\tableparrot};%
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE the numbers above the bars are wrong. I suppose that’s because I’m switching to integers. I’m not having that problem in my actual document. I have no clue where that comes from here. Anyway, that second MWE shows what I want to plot. This is the output:

[image]

Comment: As you can see there either doesn't seem to be an (easy) answer to your question or your question is not totally clear. I am currently not 100% sure if I am sure what output you expect. Could you edit your question and maybe add a sketch of the expected result?

Comment: I added a second MWE, that shows what I’m trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it would be even better if you would (additionally) add an **image** of the result.

Comment: I’ve added an image of the output of the second MWE. The numbers generated by nodes near coords are wrong as I said. Maybe someone understands what I intended to do by looking at the code and knows how to get it right. This is about getting the bars coloured, anyway. If there is a proper solution for that, without my ifthenelse hack, then the numbers should automatically be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way how you could achieve what you want. But be aware that this is not very efficient for large tables, because for each `\addplot` that uses the filter *the whole table* needs to be fully processed.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Thing;Weight
Dog 1;50
Dog 2;45
Cat 1;10
Cat 2;10
Cat 3;11
Parrot;3
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\table}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % filter away stuff in column #1 which starts with string #2 of
        % table \table
        discard if not/.style 2 args={
            % adapted from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66716/95441>
            x filter/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{#1}\of{\table}
                \IfBeginWith{\pgfplotsretval}{#2}{}{\def\pgfmathresult{}}
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar=3mm,
        bar shift=0pt,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\table}{Thing},
        x tick label style={rotate=60},
    ]
        % dummy to plot all `xtick`s
        \addplot [forget plot] table [x expr=\coordindex,y expr=0] {\table};

        % cycle through entries
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {Dog,Cat,Parrot} {
            \addplot+ [
                nodes near coords,
                % apply style
                discard if not={Thing}{#1},
            ] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=1] {\table};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really looks like what I’m looking for. I didn’t know `forget plot`. That makes things easier. I think I understand what your codes does. PGF is overwhelmingly complex. Would it be possible to include a list of colours and to connect it to the foreach list, something like `\addplot+[\colourindex{#1}]`? Regarding efficiency, I think more than about 30–40 bars in one plot would be too much information anyway. Do you think, it could be done easier or more efficient using Lua?

Comment: There are several ways to adapt the bar colors. One would be to create a custom `cycle list` and use it. When you search for that here (on TeX.SX) you will find several answers which will fit your needs. Good luck.

Comment: I was only half lucky. I defined to lists, one with colours, one just with `fill`. Then I wrote `cycle multiindex* list={my colors\nextlist my fills\nextlist}` inside `\pgfplotsset`. That ain’t doin’ anythin’. I have to use `cycle multiindex* list={my colors\nextlist my fills\nextlist}` as one of the options of `\begin{axis}[]`. `ybar` as another option overrides `cycle multiindex* list={my colors\nextlist my fills\nextlist}` from `\pgfplotsset`. But it works.

Comment: That is, because in the `ybar` style the `bar cycle list` cycle list is called and thus overrides your `cycle list`. Depending on your *other* needs for your real document there are several options to avoid stating your defined `cycle list` to the `axis` options after the `ybar` call. E.g. if you *always* want to use your defined `cycle list` in the `ybar` plots you could append it to the ybar style by stating it in `ybar/.append style={...}`. Another to define you own `ybar` style like `my ybar/.style={ybar,...}` and of course than call this.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot this topic. One day [TM], I want to make a clean, tidy collection of everything I need or needed in PGF, so this is going into that collection.