# How to plot data from multiple filters using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm searching for a way to apply multiple filters to a data input and plot the result of each filter in one axis environment. I found the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/how-can-i-filter-select-data-from-a-table-and-plot-it) which applies one filter but uses the filter in an axis environment. Having multiple axis environment in a tikz picture ends up in weird results. Any idea how to achieve that for multiple filters/plots.

EDIT:
here an example:

```
P X Y
0 1 0.882352941176
0 2 11.0
0 3 11.0
0 4 6.0
0 5 3.0
0 6 1.0625
0 7 0.689655172414
0 8 0.541125541126
0 9 0.519576719577

1 1 1.13333333333
1 2 7.0
1 3 4.0
1 4 2.66666666667
1 5 1.2
1 6 0.594594594595
1 7 0.447368421053
1 8 0.423202614379
1 9 0.410808614384
```

I want to plot a parametrized plot For each `P` I want to create a line plot with `X` and `Y` values from the according `X` and `Y` column. I want to filter for each `P` and then plot all the results in one axis.
Sorry for providing this only after being asked for.

Comment: I freely admit knowing nothing about tikz and pgfplots, but could you be more specific on what you mean by "filters".  Are you trying to process a block of numbers, or are you talking about image transparancies, etc.?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry that I didn't provide any code but I'm completely unsure about how to achieve what I described, but the referenced question gives an example ob the filter I want to apply on the input data (numbers) before plotting the results of all filters in one axis-environment.

Comment: OK, so you want to filter the data.  The answer will depend on whether you want, as the referenced question said, to only plot lines with a particular number.  Other filters might be plot every nth line.  Others might be to extract column 3 from the file.  Each answer might involve different tools.  The readarray package will read a data file and stick each data element into a separate variable, so that you could recall cell 4,3 with \Arrayij{4}{3}.  That might help you filter.  If you need to take a cell's data and process it, like removing decimal points, stringstrings package might help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want to plot multiple groups of lines each group with a particular number. I will add an example of the data I try to plot to my question, sorry that I didn't give an example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the approach from [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on) to filter the data in each of your `\addplot` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
P X Y
0 1 0.882352941176
0 2 11.0
0 3 11.0
0 4 6.0
0 5 3.0
0 6 1.0625
0 7 0.689655172414
0 8 0.541125541126
0 9 0.519576719577

1 1 1.13333333333
1 2 7.0
1 3 4.0
1 4 2.66666666667
1 5 1.2
1 6 0.594594594595
1 7 0.447368421053
1 8 0.423202614379
1 9 0.410808614384       
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [ultra thick, black, discard if not={P}{0}] table [x=X, y=Y] {data.dat};
\addplot [ultra thick, red, discard if not={P}{1}] table [x=X, y=Y] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got a problem applying your solution. It turn out that the `\else` is always executed. It occurred to me that the headers in the solution you referred to are given in brackets `{}` but adding these to my data didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't read your answer to the other question carefully enough. The problem was that I did supply a table instead of a datafile to `\addplot`