# using more than 2 arguments in a pgfplots style

Tags: macros, pgfplots

Based on [How to plot data from multiple filters using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106084/how-to-plot-data-from-multiple-filters-using-pgfplots) I got a follow up one. I would like to filter not only for one value of P for each plot but for also for X values that are smaller than a given value. Here is how I tried to achieve it.

```
  \pgfplotsset{
    discard if not and smaller/.style 4 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \edef\tempc{\thisrow{#3}}
            \edef\tempd{#4}
            \ifnum\tempa=\tempb
                \ifnum\tempc<\tempd
                    \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
                \else
                \fi
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [ultra thick, black, discard if not and smaller={P}{0}{X}{5}] table [x=X, y=Y] {data.dat};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But pdfLaTeX tells me that:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/discard if not and sm
aller/.style 4 args' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

How can I pass these 4 arguments so that pgfplots find the style definition?

Comment: Hi soriak. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More than two arguments require `/.style n args={no of args}{....}` or `/.code n args={no of arguments}{....}`

```
  \pgfplotsset{
    discard if not and smaller/.style n args={4}{
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \edef\tempc{\thisrow{#3}}
            \edef\tempd{#4}
            \ifnum\tempa=\tempb
                \ifnum\tempc<\tempd
                    \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
                \else
                \fi
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [ultra thick, 
              black, 
              discard if not and smaller={P}{0}{X}{5}] table [x=X, y=Y] {data.dat};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

If you have a certain pattern when entering these arguments instead of consecutive braces `{1}{2}{3}{4}` etc. you can also use

```
/.style args={#1 and #2 using color #3 and size #4}
```

or anything else so that you can supply arguments

```
mykey=a and b using color white and size 2cm
```

Same holds for `/.code args` too.

Comment: Could you make yoúr MWE runable?