# Superposed sparsity patterns in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have two sparsity patterns that I would like to show, one on top of the other, but so far all I could find in tex sx is how to create a simple sparsity pattern.

The patern I would like to create is like this one:

[image]

I can do both sparsity patterns separately, using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread{data1.dat}\firsttable
\pgfplotstableread{data2.dat}\secondtable
\def\nrows{21}
\def\ncols{21}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nrows}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,\ncols}{
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of\firsttable
            \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=0\relax\else
            \node[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum size=15pt, inner sep=5pt, fill=gray!\pgfplotsretval!red, opacity=0.\pgfplotsretval] at (\j*20 pt,-\i*20 pt) {};
            \fi
        };
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\nrows}{
            \foreach \j in {0,...,\ncols}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of\secondtable
                \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=0\relax\else
                \node[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum size=15pt, inner sep=5pt, fill=gray!\pgfplotsretval!blue, opacity=0.\pgfplotsretval] at (\j*20 pt,-\i*20 pt) {};
                \fi
            };
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{key}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I would like to have both of them superposed.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Sorry, but so far I don't have an idea where your problem is. Could you edit your question and add what you have achieved so far, including the data you want to plot, best in table form (like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300349/95441)). If you don't need exactly the shown red mark, but only something similar, this should be really easy to do.

Comment: I added code of what two sparsity patterns, basically I would like to have these two sparsity patterns superposed. If the result can look closer to the figure above that would be great, but the shape of the dots doesn't need to be the same as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility to achieve what you want. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
    \begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
        1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
        1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
    \end{filecontents}
    % create another table for the axis tick labels
    \begin{filecontents}{AxisTickLabels.dat}
        A
        B
        C
        D
        E
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread{data1.dat}\firsttable
    % this table has to be loaded because otherwise it is assumed the table
    % has a header and thus the first element would be missing
    \pgfplotstableread[header=false]{AxisTickLabels.dat}\AxisLabels

    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\firsttable}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\NumberOfRowsFirst{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\firsttable}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\NumberOfColsFirst{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % reverse the y axis
        y dir=reverse,
        % only show the marks
        only marks,
        % draw ticks on each index ...
        xtick={0,...,\NumberOfRowsFirst},
        ytick={0,...,\NumberOfColsFirst},
        % ... and label them according the data given in the loaded table
        xticklabels from table={\AxisLabels}{[index]0},
        yticklabels from table={\AxisLabels}{[index]0},
        % format the ticklabel nodes in tiny so the entries don't overlap
        xticklabel style={
            node font=\tiny,
        },
        yticklabel style={
            node font=\tiny,
        },
        % align the legend entries text to the left
        legend cell align=left,
    ]

        % because we want legend entries, draw the first column separately
        \addplot [
            % state here how the marks should look like
            red,
            mark=+,
        ] table [
            % use the coordinate index for the x coordinate ...
            x expr=\coordindex,
            % ... and only draw a mark at the column index, if the entry
            % of that column entry is unequal zero
            y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrowno{0} == 0, NaN, 0)},
        ] {data1.dat};

        % now draw all the remaining columns and use `forget plot' so
        % they don't add to the legend
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach  {1,...,\NumberOfColsFirst} {
            \addplot [
                red,
                mark=+,
                forget plot,
            ] table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrowno{#1} == 0, NaN, #1)},
            ] {data1.dat};
        }

        % repeat the above with the second table
        \addplot [
            blue,
            mark=square,
        ] table [
            x expr=\coordindex,
            y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrowno{0} == 0, NaN, 0)},
        ] {data2.dat};

            \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{data2.dat}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\NumberOfColsSecond{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach  {1,...,\NumberOfColsSecond} {
            \addplot [
                blue,
                mark=square,
                forget plot,
            ] table [
                x expr=\coordindex,
                y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrowno{#1} == 0, NaN, #1)},
            ] {data2.dat};
        }

        % state the legend entries
        \legend{
            first plot,
            second plot,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]