# PGFplots: Changing style of labels of nodes near coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, nodes-near-coords

Trying to adopt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78718/2288) approach, I didn't manage to get what I want of changing the style of the `nodes near coords` labels.

I would like to make this code `poles={red, fill = blue, draw}` work and accordingly change `nodes near coords` labels styles in addition to printing the correct labels (e.g. `(-8,0)` instead of `0`).

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    poles/.style= { only marks, mark=x, mark size = 1ex, thick},
    nodes on coords/.style={
        nodes near coords,
        point meta = explicit symbolic,
        every node near coord/.style args={[#1]}%
        {
            anchor=south, label={[black,#1]\myangle:{\mylabel}}
        },
        visualization depends on={\thisrow{angle} \as \myangle},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \mylabel},
    }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{poles.dat}
    Re      Im      label       angle
    -2      2       (-2,2)      270
    -2      -2      (-2,-2)     90
    -8      0       (-8,0)      60
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[poles={red, fill = blue, draw}, nodes near coords]
        table {poles.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @marmot's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461209/2288) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106156/2288), I think I figured out how to do it the right way.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    poles/.style= { only marks, mark=x, mark size = 1ex, thick},
    point meta = explicit symbolic,
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{angle} \as \myangle},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \mylabel},
    Label Style/.style args = {#1}{
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.style = %
        {
            anchor=south, label={[#1]\myangle:{\mylabel}}
        },
    }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{poles.dat}
    Re      Im      label       angle
    -2      2       (-2,2)      270
    -2      -2      (-2,-2)     90
    -8      0       (-8,0)      60
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[Label Style={blue,fill = gray!20},poles]
        table {poles.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt of a partial answer. What it does is to allow you to add the labels to the nodes in the way I think you may have had in mind. In your code, you have a style `nodes on coords`, which you define but never use. More specifically, you use `nodes near coords` (rather than `nodes on coords`), which unless instructed otherwise, just places the `\coordindex` on top of the coordinates. Just trying to install `nodes on coords` lead to errors, so I decided to go step by step and just pasted the keys into the `axis` options after I modified them.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{my node/.style={}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    poles/.style= { only marks, mark=x, mark size = 1ex, thick},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{poles.dat}
    Re      Im      label       angle
    -2      2       (-2,2)      270
    -2      -2      (-2,-2)     90
    -8      0       (-8,0)      60
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[point meta = explicit symbolic,
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{angle} \as \myangle},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \mylabel},
        every node near coord/.append style={
            anchor=south, label={[black]\myangle:{\mylabel}}
        }]
        \addplot[poles={red, fill = blue, draw},nodes near coords]
        table {poles.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't realize that I have defined something I never used.

Comment: Thanks to your answer and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106156/2288), I managed to do it right in the answer I posted.