# How to define optional arguments for custom pgfplots style

Tags: pgfplots, parameters

I see from other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106092/7561) that it is possible to create styles with parameters. Like

```
\pgfplotsset{
  custom style/.style 2 args{
    % code that uses #1 and #2
  }
}
```

However, I can't find a way of telling the style to default to some value if those parameters are not defined.

Thus, how can I defined optional parameters in a similar way to macros.

Comment: Usually it is sufficient to add `\pgfplotsset{
  custom style/.style 2 args{
    % code that uses #1 and #2
  }, custom style={#1}{#2}
}` but it would be better to provide a concrete example.

Comment: `\pgfplotsset{custom style/.default={default value for first argument}{default value for second argument}}`

Comment: Note that this is not PGFPlots specific. All `\pgfplotsset` does is call `\pgfkeys` with the key directory set to `/pgfplots`.

Comment: @Jake that was the answer. Would you mind to make it a full answer to accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set default values for the arguments of a `.style 2 args` in the same way that you set the default argument for a standard `.style:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    custom style/.default={default value for first argument}{default value for second argument}
}
```