# Add node colors and node shapes to legend in tikz-picture using forest tree and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, forest, legend

I want to add the elements of my tree to the legend (see the legend for description). I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/legend-in-tikzpicture) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture) answer, but they do not explain how to add other shapes to the legend. I did not find anything helpful in the pgfplots-docs. I am not restricted to pgfplots for the legend, if you have another solution I will gladly use it.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,fixpdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------

% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,-0.0225){#1};
        },%
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw,minimum size = 2.25em, l sep=15pt, s sep=3.0em}
[0, fill=Apricot  
    [1, fill=SpringGreen, shape=diamond, for tree={s sep = 3.0em}  
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
    ]
    [2, fill=SpringGreen, shape=star, for tree={s sep = 3.0em}
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
      [8]
    ]
    [3, fill=SpringGreen, shape=diamond      
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
    ]
    [4, fill=Apricot
      [$\dots$, draw=none]      
    ]
    [5, fill=SpringGreen, shape=regular polygon
      [$\dots$, draw=none]      
    ]
]
\begin{customlegend}[
  legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
  Green circle/node here,
  Red circle/node here,
  White Star here, 
  White Diamond here,
  White Polygon here
  },
  legend style={at={(4.5,3.5)},font=\footnotesize}] % <= to define position and font legend
  % the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
      \addlegendimage{mark=ball,ball color=SpringGreen, draw=white}
      \addlegendimage{mark=ball,ball color=Apricot, draw=white}
      \addlegendimage{stealth-stealth,red,opacity=0.4}
      \addlegendimage{number in legend=1,blue}
      \addlegendimage{number in legend=0,red}
  \end{customlegend}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. You can tried also with `istgame` package: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/istgame/istgame-doc.pdf

Comment: I didn't see a reply from `Schrödinger's cat` for long time !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style for shapes in the legend similar to your current `number in legend` style, for example called `shape in legend`. The style for shapes can be defined to accept two arguments, the shape and the color, using `.style 2 args`. This is called with `shape in legend={arg1}{arg2}` (see [How to plot data from multiple filters using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106084/how-to-plot-data-from-multiple-filters-using-pgfplots)). The style itself draws a normal node that uses the shape and fill color as arguments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------

% definition to insert numbers and shapes
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,-0.0225){#1};
        },%
        },
        /pgfplots/shape in legend/.style 2 args={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node[draw,#1,fill=#2,minimum width=3mm] at (0.295,-0.0225){};
        },%
        },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw,minimum size = 2.25em, l sep=15pt, s sep=3.0em}
[0, fill=Apricot  
    [1, fill=SpringGreen, shape=diamond, for tree={s sep = 3.0em}  
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
    ]
    [2, fill=SpringGreen, shape=star, for tree={s sep = 3.0em}
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
      [8]
    ]
    [3, fill=SpringGreen, shape=diamond      
      [$\dots$, draw=none]
    ]
    [4, fill=Apricot
      [$\dots$, draw=none]      
    ]
    [5, fill=SpringGreen, shape=regular polygon
      [$\dots$, draw=none]      
    ]
]
\begin{customlegend}[
  legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
  Green circle/node here,
  Red circle/node here,
  White Star here, 
  White Diamond here,
  White Polygon here
  },
  legend style={at={(4.5,3.5)},font=\footnotesize}] % <= to define position and font legend
  % the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
      \addlegendimage{shape in legend={circle}{SpringGreen}}
      \addlegendimage{shape in legend={circle}{red}}
      \addlegendimage{shape in legend={star}{white}}
      \addlegendimage{shape in legend={diamond}{white}}
      \addlegendimage{shape in legend={regular polygon}{white}}
  \end{customlegend}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]