# pgfplots: Plotting one subfigure per country, from datafile

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have data in csv format at the country-year level, and using pgfplots I would like to plot a given variable over time, with one subfigure per country. My idea was to use a `groupplot` environment: and a loop inside, that would loop over the set of countries, and "filter out" data to keep only one country.

The issue is that I am not even able to filter data to keep only one country. This is my (non)working example, adapted from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/how-can-i-filter-select-data-from-a-table-and-plot-it), trying to filter on `country == GER`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{CountryYears.csv}
    country,year,vartoplot
    AUT,1998,.1
    AUT,1999,.2
    AUT,2000,.7
    GER,1999,.4
    GER,2000,.45
    GER,2001,.7
    GER,2002,.6
    FRA,2000,.5
    FRA,2001,.75
    FRA,2002,.57894
    FRA,2003,.549
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{columns/country/.style={string type}}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{CountryYears.csv}\loadeddata

      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      x filter/.code={\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{country}\of{\loadeddata}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tempva}{\pgfplotsretval == GER ? 1: 0}
        \ifnum\tempva>0%true
        \else%false
        \def\pgfmathresult{}
        \fi
      },
      ]
      \addplot[only marks] table[x=year,y=vartoplot] {\loadeddata};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I supsect it doesn't work because I'm trying to filter on a string column? (The one containing the country.) But not even sure about that. Anwyay, I would appreciate some pointers as to either the filtering problem, or perhaps some suggestion on a more elegant approach to doing these country subgraphs.

Answer (score 1):

First define a string as follows:

```
\def\AUTstring{AUT}
```

and then write your filter like

```
    x filter/.code={
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{country}\of{\loadeddata}
        \ifx\pgfplotsretval\AUTstring
        \else
            \pgfmathparse{inf}
        \fi
    }
```

That is, if `\pgfplotsretval` is `AUT` then do nothing. Otherwise drop this point.