# PGFplot plot y over x where z=bar (comparable to SQL WHERE clause)

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv, axis

I am using TexLive XuaLatex with PGFplots 1.13 to plot data. I have a table like this:

```
 x , y  , z
 0 , 0  , 0 
 0 , 0  , 1 
 1 , 1  , 0 
 1 , 1  , 1 
 2 , 2  , 0 
 2 , 4  , 1 
 3 , 3  , 0 
 3 , 9  , 1 
 4 , 4  , 0 
 4 , 16 , 1 
 5 , 5  , 0 
 5 , 25 , 1 
 6 , 6  , 0 
 6 , 36 , 1
```

How can I use the PGFplot axis-environment to plot y over x where z=bar, when bar is a number. I'm thinking kind of the way you can access data with [MySQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma]
        \addplot
            table[x=x,y=y,WHERE z=0, col sep=comma]
            {DATA.csv};

        \addplot
            table[x=x,y=y,WHERE z=1,col sep=comma]
            {DATA.csv};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have not found anything on that in the guide. I do not want a solution that omits the question by having a table like that:

```
x,   y1,   y2
```

and then do plot with x=x, y=y1 and a second plot with x=x, y=y2.

This might be a handy solution for the simple example I am giving but it does not work for my problem, because in the real problem there are 10 different y to be plotted over x for 4 different z, and I really don't want the implementation like the solution proposed for several reasons.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Have you looked at/tried `x filter/.code` (or its `y/z` equivalent) yet?
See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66192/131649 or the pgfplots manual section 4.22 (p.383f in v1.14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are several ways of doing this. One way would be to use `y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrow{z}==0,\thisrow{y},nan}` instead of `y=y`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{DATA.csv}
x,y,z
0,0,0
0,0,1
1,1,0
1,1,1
2,2,0
2,4,1
3,3,0
3,9,1
4,4,0
4,16,1
5,5,0
5,25,1
6,6,0
6,36,1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma]
        \addplot
            table[x=x,y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrow{z}==0,\thisrow{y},nan)}, col sep=comma]
            {DATA.csv};

        \addplot
            table[x=x,y expr={ifthenelse(\thisrow{z}==1,\thisrow{y},nan)},col sep=comma]
            {DATA.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]